# SQL Query creation with multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working with MYSQL, and want to create a query. I have 3 tables.

###### QUESTION

| QUESTION_NUMBER | QUESTION_DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | anydesc |
| 2 | anydesc2 |

###### ANSWER

| ANSWER_NUMBER | ANSWER_DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | anydescANS |
| 2 | anydesc2ANS |
| 3 | anydesc3ANS |

And a bridge TABLE

###### QUESTION_ANSWER

| Q_NUM | A_NUM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

Now I want to retrieve all the Answers of let's say a specific QUESTION NUMBER i.e 1.

What I have tried.

```sql
SELECT QUESTION.QUESTION_NUMBER, QUESTION.QUESTION_DESCRIPTION, ANSWER.ANSWER_NUMBER, ANSWER.ANSWER_DESCRIPTION

FROM QUESTION
RIGHT JOIN QUESTION_ANSWER ON QUESTION.QUESTION_NUMBER=4

INNER JOIN ANSWER ON QUESTION_ANSWER.Q_NUM=4
```

and similar queries, but I can not make sense of it, and can not get desired output.

What I want is to get all the answers that belong to specific Question Number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it this way:

```
SELECT 
  Q.QUESTION_NUMBER, 
  Q.QUESTION_DESCRIPTION, 
  A.ANSWER_NUMBER, 
  A.ANSWER_DESCRIPTION
FROM QUESTION AS Q
INNER JOIN QUESTION_ANSWER AS QA ON Q.QUESTION_NUMBER = QA.Q_NUM
INNER JOIN ANSWER AS A ON QA.A_NUM = A.ANSWER_NUMBER
WHERE Q.QUESTION_NUMBER=4;
```

You don't need RIGHT OUTER JOIN, you need INNER JOIN, because there is certain to be a matching question if you are seeking answers.

I recommend avoiding the "comma-style" join syntax. That was made obsolete in 1989. It works the same as inner join, but it's worth using the modern syntax consistently.

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for your purpose:

```
SELECT q.question_number, q.question_description,
       a.answer_number,   a.answer_description
FROM question q, answer a, question_answer qa
WHERE q.question_number = qa.q_num
  AND a.answer_number   = qa.a_num
  AND q.question_number = 2
```